# Exclude values "starting with" from column in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I have DataGrid to display table from Database. I am also collecting properties for filter.

Here is my code:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _conditions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void UpdateFilter()
{
    var activeConditions = _conditions.Where(c => c.Value != null).Select(c => "(" + c.Value + ")");
    DataView dv = DataGrid1.ItemsSource as DataView;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", activeConditions);
}

private void NameSearch_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string filter = NameSearch.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        _conditions["name"] = null;
    else
        _conditions["name"] = string.Format("NAME Like '%{0}%'", filter);
    UpdateFilter();
}

private void CustomerNumberSearch_TextChanged_1(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string filter = CustomerNumberSearch.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        _conditions["nro"] = null;
    else
        _conditions["nro"] = string.Format("NRO Like '%{0}'", filter); //this should be "Begins with" not "Like"
    UpdateFilter();
}

private void ActiveCustomer_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveCustomer.IsChecked == true)
    {
        _conditions["active"] = string.Format("ACTIVE Like '%{0}%'", "1");
        UpdateFilter();
    }
    else
    {
        _conditions["active"] = null;
        UpdateFilter();
    }
}
```

How, instead of one parameter in textbox `"NRO Like '%{0}'", filter`:

```
private void CustomerNumberSearch_TextChanged_1(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string filter = CustomerNumberSearch.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        _conditions["nro"] = null;
    else
        _conditions["nro"] = string.Format("NRO Like '%{0}'", filter); //this should be "Begins with" not "Like"
    UpdateFilter();
}
```

I can exclude everything except numbers starting with 2 and 3?

In Column `NRO` I have like:

```
1575
8589445
5465858
3545664
3545688
2894489
2686886
3898984
8978556
6548898
```

I can make a checkbox but what would be the filter criteria to leave only?:

```
3545664
3545688
2894489
2686886
3898984
```

Comment: Ok, I guess I got it. Should be `"NRO Like '2%' OR NRO Like '3%'"`. Then I can make checkbox for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody wondering the same. Here is solution I have used in my case:

```
   private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            _conditions["criteria1"] = string.Format("NRO Like '2%' OR NRO Like '3%'");
            UpdateFilter();
        }
        else
        {
            _conditions["criteria1"] = null;
            UpdateFilter();
        }
    }
```